# Varias cuentas atrás a la vez en javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito mostrar varias cuentas atrás a la vez. Los datos se tomarán de una base de datos y podrá ser una sóla cuenta o más de una. A continuación pongo un ejemplo:

```js
//var a = [4, 5, 6];
var a=[];
var b={};
for(var i=3;i<6;i++)
{
  b = {segundos: (i+1), elemento: 'demo' + (i+1)};
  a.push(b);
}

function mifun(X)
{
  if(X.segundos>0) 
  {
    document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = X.segundos;
    X.segundos--;
  }
  else document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
}

setInterval(function(){mifun(a[0]);},1000);
setInterval(function(){mifun(a[1]);},1000);
setInterval(function(){mifun(a[2]);},1000);
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span>
```

Esto es un pequeño ejemplo. Los datos se obtienen en PHP y luego los paso a un vector en JavaScript. El tamaño del vector podrá variar en función de la información guardada.

En este caso llamo a la función `setInterval` en tres ocasiones (`a[0]`, `a[1]` y `a[2]`). Pero el tamaño real del vector no será siempre el mismo. ¿Cómo se podría llamar a la función setInterval sin tener que escribir esas 3 últimas líneas?

He probado a meterla en un bucle como el siguiente pero no funciona:

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
    setInterval(function(){mifun(a[i]);},1000);
```

Comment: ¿Qué o cómo no funciona cuando pones las llamadas en un bucle?

Comment: No funciona, no hace la cuenta atrás correctamente. Si por ejemplo pongo esto: for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) setInterval(function(){mifun(a[i]);},1000); Verás que no se ejecuta correctamente, no sale nada en pantalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que cuando lo pones en un bucle, se recorre el array con el índice `i`, pero cuando se llama a `setInterval` el valor de `i` ya no es el mismo (se ha movido el bucle), lo cual va a causar que fallen las cuentas.

Una posible solución sería cambiar la definición de la variable, para que en lugar de ser con `var` sea con `let` y ya te funcionará el bucle:

```js
//var a = [4, 5, 6];
var a=[];
var b={};
for(var i=3;i<6;i++)
{
  b = {segundos: (i+1), elemento: 'demo' + (i+1)};
  a.push(b);
}

function mifun(X)
{
  if(X.segundos>0) 
  {
    document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = X.segundos;
    X.segundos--;
  }
  else document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
}

for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
    setInterval(function(){mifun(a[i]);},1000);
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span>
```

Con `let` se está especificando que el ámbito de la variable es sólo en el bloque en que se llama (en tu caso, el bucle `for`) y no la función completa, funcionando como una clausura, por lo que no tienes el problema de que `i` no esté bien definida después del `for`.

---

Si no quieres usar `let` porque quieres darle un soporte más amplio a navegadores antiguos ([como sugiere Arnau Castellví en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83027/varias-cuentas-atr%C3%A1s-a-la-vez-en-javascript/83035?noredirect=1#comment153427_83035)), lo que puedes hacer es crear tu propia clausura y seguir usando `var`:

```js
//var a = [4, 5, 6];
var a=[];
var b={};
for(var i=3;i<6;i++)
{
  b = {segundos: (i+1), elemento: 'demo' + (i+1)};
  a.push(b);
}

function mifun(X)
{
  if(X.segundos>0) 
  {
    document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = X.segundos;
    X.segundos--;
  }
  else document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
}

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setInterval(function(){mifun(a[i]);},1000);
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span>
```

Comment: Ojo con el let, aun hay muchos navegadores que no lo conocen, androids antiguos y tal...

Comment: @ArnauCastellví gracias por la nota, añadí una alternativa con un pequeño ejemplo usando clausuras en lugar de `let`

Comment: Muchas Gracias! No entiendo muy bien el concepto de clausura. Según he leído es cuando una función que está declarada dentro de otra función, tiene acceso a las variables de la primera función. En este caso hay que poner la función principal entre paréntesis y poner entre paréntesis también la variable "i" para que tenga acceso a ella y no se modifique su valor. Es así?

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución es que tu bucle for tenga una closure pasandole `i`, esto hará que `i` este en el mismo contexto cuando ejecuta el `setInterval`.

```js
//var a = [4, 5, 6];
var a=[];
var b={};
for(var i=3;i<6;i++)
{
  b = {segundos: (i+1), elemento: 'demo' + (i+1)};
  a.push(b);
}

function mifun(X)
{
  if(X.segundos>0) 
  {
    document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = X.segundos;
    X.segundos--;
  }
  else document.getElementById(X.elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
}

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  (function (i) {
     setInterval(function(){mifun(a[i]);},1000);
    }(i));
}
```

```html
<span id=demo4></span><br>
<span id=demo5></span><br>
<span id=demo6></span>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!